# Microsoft Word Metadata on copy and paste into html (contenteditable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, metadata

I'm wondering if there is any way to ignore or strip metadata from a copied and pasted paragraph / sentence in a html div / content editable = true from Microsoft Word or other text editing program?

I am building an html app that is a text editor, but the problem is every time somebody copies and pastes text that was already formatted in another program (word, other html pages), it adds some metadata that I don't know how to strip out.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) for this as it is a WYSIWYG text editor that has that feature. There is a [Demo Page](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) that has a button at the top of the editor "Paste From Word".

If using TinyMCI is not an option you can [download it's source](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php) and determine how TinyMCE does it.

Comment: does this only cover word? i would like to get rid of some formatting info not only from word but from copied and pasted text from html pages etc...

Comment: Yes, the above answer is only concerning Word. However, you can add buttons to the TinyMCE menu if you would like. Whether you use TinyMCE or not, you could use a javascript function to strip the html. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript